# pgadmin III sequence definition

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I use pgadmin III to see the definition of a sequence. It reports

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.mytable_id_seq
  INCREMENT 0
  MINVALUE 0
  MAXVALUE 0
  START 0
  CACHE 0;
```

It did say that I do not have permission to view most of the statistics of the sequence. But the definition is displayed as above.

Does it actually means the sequence is increment by 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a PgAdmin-III bug; it should't show the sequence info at all if you don't have the rights to see it. If you can reproduce the bug on the latest version of PgAdmin-III (since you didn't mention that detail) please report it to the PgAdmin-III mailing list.